# Promise not executing when wrapped in a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am new to NodeJS and i am trying to post a message to AWS SNS from lambda. I took the code from AWS code samples and it is working fine in lambda.
But when i wrapped the same code in a function aand invoked from the main handler it is not working..

I tried returning and resolving the promise but nothing works.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set region

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    saveToSNS();
};

function saveToSNS()  {
    console.log("sdsdsd");
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var params = {
      Message: 'MESSAGE_TEXT', /* required */
      TopicArn: '<MY TOPIC>'
    };

    // Create promise and SNS service object
    var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states

    return publishTextPromise.then(
      function(data) {
          console.log("sdsdsd");
        console.log("Message ${params.Message} send sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}");
        console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
      }).catch(
        function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      });

}
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by removing the async keyworkd from handler. Can someone explain what was happening when async keywrd was there?

Comment: I think, you need to add `return` statement for `saveToSNS ()` call in your handler. I mean 
```exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return saveToSNS();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place all code inside the handler as well. You can try like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    // Set region
    AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

    saveToSNS();

    function saveToSNS()  {

        // Create publish parameters
        var params = {
            Message: 'MESSAGE_TEXT', /* required */
            TopicArn: 'TOPIC_ARN'
        };

        // Create promise and SNS service object
        var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();


        publishTextPromise.then(function(data) {
            console.log("Message ${params.Message} send sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}");
            console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
        });

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use async/await like this:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set region

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    await saveToSNS();
};

async function saveToSNS()  {
    console.log("sdsdsd");
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var params = {
      Message: 'MESSAGE_TEXT', /* required */
      TopicArn: '<MY TOPIC>'
    };

    // Create promise and SNS service object
    var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states

    return publishTextPromise.then(
      function(data) {
          console.log("sdsdsd");
        console.log("Message ${params.Message} send sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}");
        console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
      }).catch(
        function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      });

}
```

or add the return statement before calling saveToSNS() function, like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return saveToSNS();
};
```